# No entra al metodo

Tags: java

Al correr el programa no hace lo que esta en el metodo. Sigo sin encontrar el error creo que es algo bastante simple pero no logro verlo. Aqui el codigo

```
public class Ejercicio5 {
 public Ejercicio5(){  
 }
 public static void Par (){
       int a;
 Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Dame un numero");
     a=leer.nextInt();

     if(a%2<0){
         System.out.println("Es par");
     }
     else{
         System.out.println("No es par");
     }
 }
}

    package ejercicios;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Ejercicios {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ejercicio5.Par();  
    } 
}
```

Comment: Intenta esto: `if(a%2==0){`

Comment: Si corregi la condicion pero aun no entra al metodo, nisiquiera hace el primer print

Comment: Si llega a la linea donde solicita el numero?

Comment: Tienes algun error, intenta mover el import al principio.

Comment: Al if entra.. como mucho saldra siempre por falso.. siempre imprime no es par, no es cierto???

Comment: Ya quedo, era el import solo lo movi.

Comment: Pues añade un comentario y responde a tu pregunta :)

Answer (score 0):

Solo tenia que cambiar la condicion e importar el Scanner en el main.

```
package Ejercicios;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ejercicio5 {
  public static void Par(){
    int a;
    Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Dame un numero");
    a=leer.nextInt();

    if(a%2==0){
      System.out.println("Es par");
    } else {
      System.out.println("No es par");
    }
  }
}
```